# Configuration files management

Tags: configuration-files, configuration-management

I have a bunch of configuration files used by gradle. 
conf1 conf2 conf3 conf4 etc.
Sometimes I need to change some setting in every file or in several files.
Is there any tool(for Linux) that helps me to do that?

For example, if I want set settings1 in conf2, conf3 and in conf5 I would use something like
"set settings1=value in conf2,conf3,conf5"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with sed. Needing to change some but not all of a set of similarly-named files in a folder complicates it a bit:

`find . -name conf2 -o -name conf3 -o -name conf5 | xargs sed -i 's/settings1=/settings1=value/g'`

If you were changing all of the conf files you could just do this:

`sed -i 's/settings1=/settings1=value/g' conf*`